# let SKView = as SKView gives error

Tags: ios, swift

I'm taking this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hLOhirsXx9c and in the Gameviewcontroller.swift i get the error

**Expected initial value after '='**

the code is

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    var scene: GameScene!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Configure the view
        let Skview = as Skview
        Skview.multipletouchenabled = false
        // Create and Configure the Scene
        scene = GameScene(size: Skview.bounds.size)
        scene.filllmode = .AcpectFill

        // Pressent The Scene

        Skview.PresentScene(scene)
           }

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
            return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown.rawValue)
        } else {
            return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All.rawValue)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

        override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
            return true
        }
    }
```

The error is at the `let skview = as Skview`

Comment: If you want to initialize a new `Skview`, use `let skview = Skview()`

Comment: as in Swift is a cast and you need to have an object that you're casting. Currently you're casting nothing as Skview so the compiler has no idea what you're talking about

Comment: Where did you get `let Skview = as Skview` from? That makes no sense, and I cannot see that code in the tutorial nor in the source code https://github.com/prometheon/MLNimbleNinja which is linked on that YouTube page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do but here is the issue:

`let Skview = (Missing Variable Here To Cast) as Skview`

I am going to assume this is the view controller and what you want is 
`let skView  = view as SKView`

Comment: Knight0fDragon is correct to be confused. OP's syntax does not match any known Swift syntax.

Comment: It worked but i had more errors which i googled and fixed thx